# What is automatic cache indexing in the Firebase SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Apple SDK version 10.15.0 introduced a feature that "adds the option to allow the SDK to create cache indexes automatically to improve query execution locally", linking to [this pull](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/11596). I don't see any documentation update on this and so have the following two questions:

1. What does this feature exactly do? I'm confused by the term local here. Is a local query an offline query? Or is this just an internal feature that the programmer shouldn't concern themselves with?
2. How is this option enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_query_indexes). You can enable the indexing if you want.

> Is a local query an offline query?

Basically, yes.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data) for more information.

> Or is this just an internal feature that the programmer shouldn't concern themselves with?

It's internal, but you can be as concerned as you want about how well it functions (and you can open an issue on GitHub to ask the engineers directly if something isn't working the way you expect).

> How is this option enabled?

See the documentation I linked at the top.

Comment: According to the dox, automatic indexing is disabled by default. It must be enabled each time the app starts, and it is then that the SDK does its optimizing. This implies that the cache isn't, or may not be, fully persistent, but cache persistence must be enabled to use this feature so there must be some persistence. Either way, I don't see the downside of this feature and so I'm curious what the tradeoff is since there is already a cache consuming disk space. Can you speak to the possible tradeoffs of enabling this feature? It seems like a no-brainer that should be on by default.

Comment: No, I can't. Why don't you start a conversation on [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk)?